# Escaping issue in maxscript

Tags: escaping, 3dsmax, maxscript

I have some issues with the edittext of maxscript and string escaping.
First, I want to escape the string written in an edittext (accents and simple quotes). The purpose is to feed this string to a mysql query.

Then I’d like to limit the number of characters per line in the edittext, force line breaks when the visual width is reached.

Are those things possible in a simple way ? I do not want to parse all the charcaters in the string and insert line breaks or espace the special characters manually.

Thnaks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Escaping the original string is easy:

```
-- origString = string from text box
substituteString origString  "\\" "\\\\"
substituteString origString  "\"" ""\\\"
```

For mySQL I'd probably do this for inverted commas:

```
substituteString origString  "\"" "'"
```

Also if you wanted to escape TAB characters etc this would work:

```
substituteString origString  (bit.intAsChar 9) "<TAB HERE>"
```

Check out http://www.asciitable.com for character numbers.

But remember the string will be stored with the escape characters, so if you read the string you will display escape characters as well.

What is this being used for?
Are you trying to display the results on a web page from mySQL?

As for line breaks I don't think there's a way to get the string per line of a Maxscript EditText box.  However you could use a .Net text box in your Maxscript UI and read it that way.